# Mysql: what situation(s) will cause index failure

Tags: mysql, indexing

Let's suppose you have a table called `user_card_tbl` which contains fields `userid`,`cardno` etc. And you have created index as seen below:

```
CREATE INDEX cardno_idx ON user_card_tbl(cardno);
```

I just want to know, what situation(s) will cause `cardno_idx` failure when you execute query.

Comment: what do you mean, "failure"? failure to update/create the index, or failure to USE the index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If some other index is better.
- If more than something like 20% of the rows have the particular value for `cardno`
- If you are using certain types of `WHERE`: `REGEXP`, `LIKE` with a leading wildcard, etc.
- If you are using `OR` (in some cases).
- If `cardno` is `VARCHAR`, but you are testing against a number that is not quoted.
- And probably many more.

If you provide a particular case, we can discuss the details.